# Ionic 2/Angular- Pinging an express server to prevent using app with no connection

Tags: ios, angular, express, ionic2

My app requires being connected to our server for any use. I wrote this function in the app component to prevent the user from using the app if the server is not available

app.component.ts

```
pingServer(){
    this.api.pingServer().subscribe(result => {
          if (result.success) {
            return true;
          }
          else {
            return false
          }
        },
        error=>{
          return false;
        }
        );
  }
}
```

this function just makes the request to our server, which I verified is hitting the right address

initializeApp() {
    console.log("initialize");

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  console.log("platform ready");
  this.screenOrientation.lock('portrait');
  console.log('Orientation is ' + this.screenOrientation.type);

  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

  let serverAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Error',
    subTitle: 'We are unable to reach our servers at this time. Please try again later',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    if(this.pingServer){
      console.log('pinged server successfully');
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
    }
    else{
      console.log('unable to ping server');
      return serverAlert.present();
    }


  }, 3000);
```

On the server side:

```
router.get( '/ping', ( req, res, next ) => {
  return res.json( { success: true } );



} )
```

This worked fine when testing on the browser. However, when using iOS it says it pings successfully every time, meanwhile, the server isn't receiving the request.